# Message sent to turtlesim does not execute

Tags: ros, velocity, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sending a velocity command message to turtlesim from a C++ program.  If I put the message in my main(), it does not appear to execute even though it shows up as a rostopic.  If I put the the message in a 'for' or 'while' loop for some number of iterations, it will execute.  I thought that (according to the tutorials) that turtlesim executed each velocity command for one second.  Can anyone tell me why a single command does not execute for the one second interval?

Running lucid, electric.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11586/message-sent-to-turtlesim-does-not-execute./) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Paul,
have a look at [publish exactly one message](http://answers.ros.org/question/2151/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message)..

This might be helpful

---

Originally posted by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) with karma: 174 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1